# Identifier Stack error

Tags: c

I'm trying to compile my code and I'm receiving this error

```
error: expected identifier or '(' before '.' token
stack.T++;
```

Here is a code snippet from my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
int * data; // array of the data on the stack
int size;
int T;
int x;
int a[];
} stack;



void push(T, x) {
    printf("\nT value%d",T);
    stack.T++;
    printf("\nT value%d",T);
    stack.a[stack.T]=x;
    printf("\n array value at position T %d",stack.a[stack.T]);
}
```

I can't seem to figure out why its giving me this error.

Comment: What do you expect? What is that line of code supposed to do?

Comment: Are you seriously using K&R style function declarations in 2016?

Comment: You have to `stack aStack;` first

Comment: @EOF :( I dunno. Its what my prof has taught us. Would it be better to write it this way - stack->T++?

Comment: The problem is that `stack` isn't a variable name, it's a type name crested with `typedef`.

Comment: @Olaf Hey! I'm expecting T to increment by 1 each time push is called. I tried to just do T++; but it gave me an error as well.

Comment: @sunqingyao Okay, I'll give that a shot!

Comment: @Code_Penguin Do you understand what `typedef` does?

Comment: @Barmar Yea, I assumed I wasn't able to use it this way. I tried just using stack T++; but I got this compiler error
`error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '++' token
       stack T++;`

Comment: You can't do the increment at the same time that you declare the variable.

Comment: Declaring it within the function or within main prior to running it would solve this then I assume  - I'll try doing this then, Thank you!

Comment: @Barmar My understanding is its a way to create a type alias - ie like int

Comment: @Code_Penguin: In that case you have some missconceptions about the C syntax and semantics. Consulting a C book or your tutor would be a good idea.

Comment: Don't use all-upercase names for anything other than macros or enum-constants. Also you should use self-explanatory names `T` or `x` don't serve that purpose - actually they defy redability.

Comment: @Olaf Will do! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `stack` type definition to declare a variable.

```
void push(stack *st, int x) {
    printf("\nT value%d", st->T);
    if (st->T >= st->size) {
        printf("\nStack size limit reached, can't push.");
        return;
    }
    st->T++;
    printf("\nT value%d",st->T);
    st->a[st->T]=x;
    printf("\n array value at position T %d",st->a[st->T]);
}
```

I've also changed the function to accept a pointer to a stack rather than a stack. Otherwise, it's pushing onto a copy of the stack, and the changes it makes will not be visible to the caller.

Comment: Thanks Barmar! I tried this and it fixed the compile error but it also presented me with another saying `error: wrong type argument to increment
     T++;`

Comment: I'll include the stackfull() within the function of push. That is a good idea, thanks

Comment: I didn't notice the `size` field before, I've updated my code to check it.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting that error.

Comment: Ah, probably something to do with my GCC compiler. =/ Just downloaded it so I'm expecting bugs.

Comment: That's very unlikely. You've probably copied my answer incorrectly.

Comment: Oh, okay I'll have another look at it then. Thanks :) Also the pointer method you're using replaces st.T++ into st->T++ by creating a pointer input in the function that points to the stack?

Comment: Yes, that's what it does.

Comment: Thats really cool!